# How to check if a directory exists in elisp?

Tags: directories

I've seen how to check if a file exists (`file-exists-p`), but how to check if a directory exists?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From elisp [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Kinds-of-Files.html#Kinds-of-Files):

> -- Function: file-directory-p filename
>
> ```
> This function returns ‘t’ if FILENAME is the name of an existing
>  directory, ‘nil’ otherwise.
> ```

See also its docstring, with a note concerning symlinks:

> (file-directory-p FILENAME)
>
> Return t if FILENAME names an existing directory.
>   Symbolic links to directories count as directories.
>   See ‘file-symlink-p’ to distinguish symlinks.

Answer (score 15):

`file-directory-p` is your friend.

Found using `C-u C-h a directory RET` and browsing the result.

Comment: @Drew Thanks, but I had copied the key sequence wrong. Fixed now.